# Interface using subclass as field type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface

I need to reference a specific SubClass AIState of an Interface IState within another Subclass AIContext, that uses the same Interface class as the generic type in IState... I have trouble with parsing correctly.

I am building a Statemachine, that works based on context: Means each state + SM exists once and whoever uses the SM just calls the Function in the class with a context as Parameter.
The context references

I have the Interfaces

```
public interface IStateContext
{
   IState<IStateContext> CurrentState { get; }
}

Interface IState <T> where T:IStateContext {
  Execute(T context);
}
```

I  implement my state for AI Behavior with a **color** to visualize:

```
public class AIState : IState <AIContext> {
   Color stateColor;
   Execute(AIState) { //behavior}
}
```

OK.
Now the issue begins. I can only create an AIContext like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class AIContext : IStateContext 
{
    public AI ai;
    public Animator animator;
    public NavMeshAgent agent;

    private IState<IStateContext> activeState;
    public IState<IStateContext> ActiveState
    {
        get => activeState;
        set => activeState = value;
    }
}
```

I need the active state to be an AIState tho, it just does not allow Subclasses... 
**I want to be able to access (AIContext) context.ActiveState.color ! But as long as it is just an IState, it doesn't have the information "color".**

Try & Error 1: I failed to parse it. It just does not let me.

Try & Error 2: I cannot use a generic type inside IStateContext that is IState, because then its just a loop of generic type declaration.....  `AIState : IState<AIContext<AIState<AI .....>>>`

I fear it's a structural problem? I hope somebody sees it.

Edit: the problem is not just  color, i might want to implement other variables later. Its the parsing. My StateMAchine just uses Generalisations (IState --> Executes them with IStateContext). I just do not see an option where I can keep the current active state in the context.

IStateContext has a IState CurrentState where T:IStateContext
while in AIState I need an AIContext CurrentState. I just cannot parse it!

Answer (score 1):

**Approach A**

If it's okay for you to force any class that implements the `IState` interface to have a `StateColor`, you can just add a property `StateColor` to your interface.

```
public interface IState<T> where T : IStateContext
{
    Color StateColor { get; set; }
    void Execute(T context);
}

public class AIState : IState<AIContext>
{
    public Color StateColor { get; set; }
    public void Execute(AIContext context) { }
}

[Serializable]
public class AIContext : IStateContext
{
    private IState<IStateContext> activeState;
    public IState<IStateContext> ActiveState
    {
        get => activeState;
        set => activeState = value;
    }

    public IState<IStateContext> CurrentState => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

This will then allow you to access the `StateColor` of your `AIContext`s property `ActiveState`:

```
var aiContext = new AIContext();
var stateColor = aiContext.ActiveState.StateColor;
```

**Approach B**

If you don't want to modify the `IState` interface, another option could be to create a new interface e.g. `IAIState` that implements the `IState` interface.

```
public interface IAIState<T> : IState<T> where T : IStateContext
{
    Color StateColor { get; set; }
}

public interface IState<T> where T : IStateContext
{
    void Execute(T context);
}
```

Then you would only have to change the type of the `activeState` field and the `ActiveState` property to `IAIState` ...

```
[Serializable]
public class AIContext : IStateContext
{
    private IAIState<IStateContext> activeState;
    public IAIState<IStateContext> ActiveState
    {
        get => activeState;
        set => activeState = value;
    }

    IState<IStateContext> IStateContext.CurrentState { get; }
}
```

... to access the `StateColor` of `ActiveState` just like mentioned above:

```
var aiContext = new AIContext();
var stateColor = aiContext.ActiveState.StateColor;
```

Comment: I think Approach B makes the most sense. I need to use AIStates in my AI specifically. I don't want to add every property i might use there to IState. The StateMachine however is supposed to run all IStates the same. I am thinking about putting the activeState property out of the context and inside the AI and just inform the StateMachine of the activeState from there, so I dont have this cross reference between State and Context happening. Just kind of wished I could have left all State-stuff out of the AI